# How keep origin index with model_selection.train_test_split?

Tags: scikit-learn

For a machine learning regression model, i use Scikit learn `model_selection.train_test_split()` function.

I have to keep somewhere the origin index into train data. I lost this information after splitting data into train/test. And i can't match data original and train data with their index.
How can i fix please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is a pandas dataframe, it is no problem to get the original indices as they are preserved in the splits:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# import some data to demonstrate
iris = datasets.load_iris(as_frame=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2)

print(X_train.index.values)
```

If your data is a numpy array, you can also just wrap it into a pandas dataframe beforehand, get the indices and proceed as you like, e.g. with the dataframe or numpy arrays.

Comment: I cannot find any official documentation on this: I only read "array-like"... Do you have a link?